# Multiple post notices cause the banner to conflict itself

Tags: bug, user-interface, community-wiki, locked-posts

In [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), there is a notice about the post being community wiki; however, this notice links to the ["Locked Posts" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts):

[image]

The text also doesn't seem to line up with Community Wiki; it seems more like something that would be for a locked post.

Comment: It is a special kind of lock, called a wiki lock. It is exception #2 for permanent locks, called out at the bottom of that Help Center article you linked to. Possibly, the new post banners are confusingly worded and need to be revised.

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah... Why would "Community Wiki" link to the "Locked Posts" page?

Comment: Well, because that’s what a Community Wiki question is: one with a single answer that is collaboratively edited/maintained. The question is locked to prevent additional answers.

Comment: @CodyGray Not necessarily. IIRC some of them have more than one answer.

Comment: Such is the ideal. Applying a wiki lock to an old question does not automatically remove all but the highest-scoring answer. They must be deleted manually by a moderator. Sometimes, when those other answers are especially useful, we feel disinclined to do so. But the point still remains that a wiki locked question cannot have any *new* answers posted, and is thus forever stuck with its current answer(s), which is maintained by the community via collaborative editing and shared ownership.

Comment: @CodyGray I think also that at one point I came across a wiki-locked question that was not community wiki. I didn't have 2K rep at the time so I wasn't allowed to edit.

Comment: This issue [was reported in an answer on the MSE question about the new post  notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337272/271271). That report was marked as [meta-tag:status-bydesign].